# JS function to update captcha image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why but my function to reload an image don't work on prod, but on dev, it's fine.
Url: http://www.gifolio.com/user/register

Click on the link "Unable to read captcha? Click here !"

The image stay the same... But on my dev, it updates fine.

Any idea?

Comment: The image is being cached. Does the `generate_captcha` script disable caching? Try adding a cache-buster to the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a cache-buster to the URL to prevent caching:

```
function reloadCaptcha() {
    jQuery('#captcha_img').attr('src', '/user/generate_captcha?cb='+(new Date().getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Technically the problem isn't caching but the browser not recognizing the URL change.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the src of the image, the browser does not get the new image because the URL is the same. To fix, you need to make sure that the URL is unique. In your `reloadCaptcha` function, set change the line to this:

```
jQuery('#captcha_img').attr('src', '/user/generate_captcha?' + Date.now());
```

Notice the change to the end of the URL. That way the browser always thinks it's getting a new image and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Why not just add a Date Time to the end of the query string?

Comment: Why did you change to use a date time?

Comment: @cgatian Just realized that the real problem wasn't server cache control but the browser not loading the image because the URL was the same.